# accidentally broke my pip install

Tags: python, 17.10, python3, pip

I just ran this command in terminal:

```
pip install --user --upgrade
```

It worked fine but now whenever I try to run pip I get this:

```
$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

These are my python paths.

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:45:48) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> import sys
>>> pp(sys.path)
['',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/smurf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages']
```

I tried re-installing pip but it didn't help.
Can someone explain how this broke and how to fix it?

Thank you,